# Sorting a "Decorated" List of Instances Using Tuples - Zelle Ex. 11.9

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, tuples

Previous related topic question did not answer my question.
If you are familiar with John Zelles - "Python Programming"
This exercise 9 Chapter 11.

No previous tuple examples have been done. Comparison methods have not been covered.

(If it had mentioned that all gpas had to be unique, then I would never have posted this question in the first place. It's actually a great book. First time anything has not been explained adequately.)

Thank you to Blckknght for setting me straight!

I have defined a class:

```
Student(name,hours,qpoints)
```

which has a method to return gpa score base on "hours" and 
"qpoints":

```
gpa()
```

I have a list of instances of Student:

```
data=[Student("Luke",40,112),Student("Gary",30,102),Student("Michelle",25,98)]
```

I want to sort this list (without using a special key function) by gpa results:

So, I create a  list of tuples:

```
stuTupList=[]


#create tuple  (float(gpa),object(Student)) for each Student in data

for stu in data:

    x,y=stu.gpa(),stu

    stuTupList.append((x,y))
```

Then I sort

```
stuTupList.sort()
```

returns:

```
[(2.8, <student.Student object at 0x03CD4D90>), (3.4, <student.Student object at 0x03CD4D50>), (3.92, <student.Student object at 0x03CD4D70>)]
```

Now, I can list the Students in gpa order:

```
gpaList=[]

for stu in stuTupList:
    gpaList.append(stu[1])

print(gpaList)


[<student.Student object at 0x03554E50>, <student.Student object at 0x03554E10>, <student.Student object at 0x03554E30>]
```

So, this works as intended, although:

Why are they printed as :

```
<student.Student object at 0x03554E50>
```

and not,

```
Student("Gary",30,108)
```

???

Anyway, here lies my real problem:

if I had a list of students written in this form:

```
data=[<student.Student object at 0x03554E50>, <student.Student object at 0x03554E10>, <student.Student object at 0x03554E30>]
```

and then use the same technique for sorting as above.

I keep getting this error!!

```
stuTupList.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Student' and 'Student'
```

Why?

Comment: "why?" Because `Student` class does not implement any of the comparison methods, see the duplicated I linked to in the comment below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To make objects of a custom class comparable, is it enough to define just a few of the members in \`\_\_eq\_\_\` and \`\_\_lt\_\_\` family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027891/to-make-objects-of-a-custom-class-comparable-is-it-enough-to-define-just-a-few)

Comment: @DeepSpace  - Thanks for the reply.  How come it works perfectly the first time around with the original list of Students?  -Not perfectly, but returns no error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tuple-based sorting solution works only if all GPA values are unique. When you compare two tuples, Python first compares their first values. If they're different, that determines the ordering of the tuple. If they're equal though, it goes on to compare the next values in each tuple with each other. If several students have the same GPA, the `Student` instances will be compared, and that's where you get your error because you can't compare one `Student` object with another.

You could work around this in several ways. One simple approach is to add a tie-breaking value into your tuples, after the GPA but before the non-comparable `Student` object. You could pick some characteristic from the students (e.g. their names), or you could just use their order in the initial list (which I'll demonstrate using the `enumerate` function):

```
for i, stu in enumerate(data):              # enumerate yields (index, value) tuples
    stuTupList.append((stu.gpa(), i, stu))  # the index is the tie-breaker, it's unique!
```

Another approach would be to make your `Student` instances directly comparable themselves. This could either be for tie-breaking purposes only (e.g. ordered by name or student ID, or whatever), or you could have the `Student` objects sort themselves by GPA by default. In any case, you need, at a minimum, to implement the `__lt__` operator to get a sortable type:

```
class Student:
    ...

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.gpa() < other.gpa()
```

Now you can just do `data.sort()` and the objects will take care of comparing GPA's themselves.

Note this is also similar to how you can get your `Student` instances to display nicely. You don't yet have a `__repr__` method implemented, so you get a default output when you print a `Student` object (`<Student object at 0xXXXX>`) instead of something nicer. You can write your own method to give the output you want:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "{}({}, {}, {})".format(type(self).__name__, self.name, self.hours, self.qpoints)
```

I don't know if I've accurately named the attributes you've set in your instances, so double check those.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed response. I'm still confused though, as all gpa scores were unique so it shouldn't have even tried to compare student instances!   :(