# How to use dunder methods for object comparison

Tags: python, class, oop, magic-methods, object-comparison

## Comparing two objects using dunder methods

I was trying to compare two 'Time objects', but I got this error:

`'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Time' and 'Time'`

This is what I tried:

1. I First initialized the 'time Class'.

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, h, m, s):
        self._h = h
        self._m = m
        self._s = s

    # Read-only field accessors
    @property
    def hours(self):
        return self._h

    @property
    def minutes(self):
        return self._m

    @property
    def seconds(self):
        return self._s
```

2. I created a method to compare the two Time objects.

```
def _cmp(time1, time2):
    if time1._h < time2._h:
        return 1
    if time1._h > time2._h:
        return -1
    if time1._m < time2._m:
        return 1
    if time1._m > time2._m:
        return -1
    if time1._s < time2._s:
        return 1
    if time1._s > time2._s:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0
```

3. I created the dunder methods.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return True if _cmp(self, other) == 0 else False

def __lt__(self, other):
    return True if _cmp(self, other) == 1 else False

def __le__(self, other):
    return True if _cmp(self, other) == 1 or _cmp(self, other) == 0 else False
```

4. I instantiated some objects, and tried comparing them (resulting in an error).

```
t1 = Time(13, 10, 5)
t2 = Time(5, 15, 30)

print(t1 < t2)
print(t2 <= t1)
```

I must surely be missing something. All tips on coding are welcome!

Comment: Can't reproduce, your code works for me.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure that you don't have a wrong indentation, so that  `__eq__`, `__lt__` and `__le__` are not part of the class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To make objects of a custom class comparable, is it enough to define just a few of the members in \`\_\_eq\_\_\` and \`\_\_lt\_\_\` family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027891/to-make-objects-of-a-custom-class-comparable-is-it-enough-to-define-just-a-few)

Comment: @moooeeeep No, that isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Matthias Oh God That's it! I forgot to indent the __eq__, __lt__ and __le__ methods. Thanks Matthias and everyone else for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many dunder-methods (or magic-methods), if you want to use `<` and `<=` then you want to use
`__lt__` for `<` and `__le__` for `<=` (stands for less-than and less-equal)

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.n <= other.n

a = A(5)
b = A(10)
print(a <= b)
```

will return True, because 5 is smaller-or-equal to 10.

Comment: You maybe set the dunders not in the class but outside of the class?

Answer (score 1):

As Matthias and Jonathan suggested, I forgot to indent the following code and placed it outside my Time class:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return True if _cmp(self, other) == 0 else False

def __lt__(self, other):
    return True if _cmp(self, other) == 1 else False

def __le__(self, other):
    return True if _cmp(self, other) == 1 or _cmp(self, other) == 0 else False
```